# Populating subform fields from main form field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm building a multi-page form with subforms for a number of tables. The form is to collect very detailed information about patients, and the patientID is included in several tables.

Can the patient ID input from the main form(master table) populate a hidden field with the same patient ID in subsequent subforms?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: By design, if you add data to a subform linked to main form by parent-child IDs, the corresponding parent id populates in any new subform record (added to recordsource even if you do not bound any form control to it). Enter data to test.

Comment: Use SQL `INSERT INTO...` statement to add `ID` from main form to subforms table.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Parfait stated the answer is yes... (at least if I understand your question correctly) You can bind these fields together using the subforms Link Master/ Child Fields Properties as circled in red[image]

But Note: If you are using a Navigation Form this same Parent/ Child linking does not exist as these sub forms are filtered. If that is the case you will have to handle this differently probably using vba.